# OpenCV multicolor thresholding

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to do a multicolor thresholding on a opencv cv2 image. The problem I am trying to solve is following:

- R, G, B each have a "valid" list
- If a pixel's R, G, B all considered valid, then make the pixel (0,0,0), otherwise, make it (255, 255, 255)

For example

- [221, 180, 50] is considered valid in R channel
- [23, 18, 2] is considered valid in G channel
- [84, 22, 48] is considered valid in B channel

Then if a pixel have any of following value (RGB order)

- (221, 23, 84)
- (221, 23, 22)
- (221, 23, 48)
- (221, 18, 84)
- (221, 18, 22)
- (221, 18, 48)
- ...
- (50, 2, 48)

it will transformed into (0,0,0), otherwise (255,255,255)

Currently, I am doing this with a nested for loop:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        imcv[y, x] = threshold(imcv[y, x])
```

where `threshold` function perform the logic described above. Note that although I did this in-place, in-place transformation is not required.

The method I currently use works, but however very slow. I believe there's must be a better method in OpenCV/Numpy. I am very new to both framework and can't figure out how.

I researched on OpenCV thresholding functions, it seems they can only work on a single channel grey scale image, also the range needs to be consecutive range. What I needed is to thresholding on all 3 channels on discrete values. I imagine there need to be a custom function to pass in, but I am unable to find the right API in their docs.

I also looked up possibly numpy API that I could utilize, like `ufunc`. It seems I can't achieve what I wanted here using it, or I didn't see how.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to both AbidRahmanK and HYRY, both solution achieved more than x1500 improvement on performance.

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1    1.576    1.576    1.576    1.576 test.py:48(preprocess_cv2_image)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 test.py:79(preprocess_cv2_image3)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 test.py:66(preprocess_cv2_image2)
```

Comment: first of all, use `xrange` instead of `range`. The latter actually builds an entire list of the specified size, and then you iterate over it, whereas the former returns a generator which doesn't have to precompute the whole list and allows you to just iterate over it.

Comment: Hi @SchighSchagh, thanks for your suggestion. Using C implementation of `range` definitely helps. I think my bottleneck here is accessing and changing each pixels in python. I think if there's an api allow me to push it into C implementation of numpy or opencv will speed it up greatly.

Comment: is [221,18,48] also valid?

Comment: Hi @AbidRahmanK Yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
z1 = np.dstack([np.in1d(img[...,0],B),np.in1d(img[...,1],G),np.in1d(img[...,2],R)]).reshape(img.shape)
q = np.all(z1,axis=2)
out = np.uint8(q)*255
```

`np.in1d(a,b)` gives you a boolean array of same length as a with `True` if that element is in b, otherwise `False`. It is just a vectorized counterpart of `in` method in Python. Or in short:

> **np.in1d(a,b) <==> [True for i in a if i in b else False]**

You perform it for all the channels, ie check first channel for valid values in B, second with G and third with R.

Then you stack them in z-direction using `np.dstack`. Why z-direction? Because we want in **BGR-BGR-BGR...** format.

But remember, this is 1D array, so we reshape it to our original image shape using `X.reshape(img.shape)` method.

So now you have a boolean mask where True if it is valid, else False.

It is all in the first line of code.

Now you want to see the valid BGR combinations. A combination is valid if all the B,G,R component is True. So you apply np.all() in z-direction. Again you get a boolean mask q

q will be a boolean mask with valid colours as True and others as False.

So you convert to integer data type, True --> 1 and False --> 0

Then you multiply it with 255. If you want the inverted image, you can use `np.bitwise_not`

Comment: Hi @AbidRahmanK, thanks for your answer! Could you kindly explain the code a little? I wanted to adapt your snippet to my code and test the performance, but I was unable to make it output a cv2 image.

Comment: Try `out = np.uint8(q)*255` now. I will update the answer soon.

Comment: You could upvote and accept the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can make three boolean array for R, G, B, if the value is valid for R, then `R[value]` is True, then you can use `Rm[img[:, :, 2]] & Gm[img[:, :, 1]] & Bm[img[:, :, 0]]` to get the result:

```
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (2000, 2000, 3))

def make_mask(idx):
    b = np.zeros(256, np.bool)
    b[idx] = True
    return b

R = [221, 180, 50]
G = [23, 18, 2]
B = [84, 22, 48]


Rm, Gm, Bm = [make_mask(v) for v in [R, G, B]]
a = Rm[img[:, :, 2]] & Gm[img[:, :, 1]] & Bm[img[:, :, 0]]
```

finally, to get the result image:

```
v = np.array([[255,255,255], [0,0,0]], np.uint8)
v[a.astype(np.uint8)]
```

Comment: Thank you @HYRY the performance is great. Your approach is very easy to understand. I am giving the answer mark to AbidRahmanK since he answered first.